# Recyclerview Redraw itself When navigating to another recycler view in Tabbed Activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

So this is the AsyncTask that I run in onCreateView in the first fragment

```
class GetDatas extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{

    Collection<ProfileDataModel> enums = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try{
            client = new OkHttpClient();
            String response = OkHttpService.GET(client, webUrl);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type type = new TypeToken<Collection<ProfileDataModel>>(){}.getType();
            enums = gson.fromJson(response, type);
            profileDataModels = enums.toArray(new ProfileDataModel[enums.size()]);
            listAdapter = new ListAdapter(Arrays.asList(profileDataModels), getContext());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        profileDataModels = enums.toArray(new ProfileDataModel[enums.size()]);
        listAdapter = new ListAdapter(Arrays.asList(profileDataModels), getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3));
    }
}
```

On the third fragment I use dummy data that does not require fetching

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
LinearLayout linearLayout;


@Override
public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video_list_pages, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.video_list_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.video_list_adapter_rootframe);

    ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(
            new String[] {
                    "mm","aa","sss","mm","aa","sss","mm","aa","sss","mm","aa","sss","mm","aa","sss"

            }
    );
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


    return rootView;
}
```

}

Some of you maybe confused by the naming, but I like to keep it that way,
[My Directory names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLfya.png)

The problem is that when I swipe to the third fragment from the first fragment, the recycle view redraws itself. This doesn't happen when I go to the second fragment, which only contains a textview
Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: what is the second fragment doing ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok whats happening is the fragment **one** is being destroyed when you go to the **third** fragment so to stop this functionality you have to override `destroyItem` and keep it blank, use it in your Activity class

```
 @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

    }
```

and your problem will be solved and next time **try to go through all methods of the class** before posting a question.
Suppose you had 4 fragments in the Tabs it will keep only 2 and destroy rest to save memory you, it can also keep 3 if you have next and previous tab like number two if you have 3 tabs, you can override it by keeping destroyItem empty cheers!

> Don't try to implement if you have scrolling 10-20 tabs your application might crash

Comment: please can you select the answer if it solved your problem for future reference?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this in OnCreate() when setting up the adapter

```
mAdapter.stateRestorationPolicy = RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY
```

This way, the adapter will save its position in case the fragment gets destroyed and recreated.